# Jasmine test expect 'toThrowError' custom error not work

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Why jasmine test does not work as expected on this code:

```
it('toThrowError test case', () => {
   expect(() => { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }).toThrowError(ArgumentOutOfRangeException);
});
```

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException is extends Error type:

```
class ArgumentOutOfRangeException extends Error {}
```

The result of the test is not as expected and the test failed:

```
Expected function to throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but it threw Error.
```

Comment: It works for me. Can't reproduce it. `"jasmine": "^3.5.0"`

Comment: @slideshowp2 my jasmine version is 3.6.0